# Javascript: wait for the execution of a previous line

Tags: javascript, css, accordion

I'm creating something similar to an  accordion, and the elements height is unknown.

```
.accordion__item .accordion__item__content {
    height: 0;
    display:block;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 0.5s ease-out;
}

.accordion__item[state=true] .accordion__item__content {
    height:auto;
    transition: height 0.5s ease;
```

Because the height is auto, on open, and transitioning to auto is not possible.
I do not want to use max-height trick, because is not very good.

So, I tried to get the height of the content element(accordion__item__content) using scrollHeight and add the value as inline-style for height;

```
 content.style.height =  content.scrollHeight + "px";
```

The issue that I have is that random, the transition part is faster than the setting of inline style height, and the transition is not working.

What I need is to delay the transition from javascript, until the height is set.

Also, not to block the loading page, will wait a max number of miliseconds.

the setTimeout is working, but it always wait for the total number of miliseconds, event if the action was done much faster.

Comment: Don't wait for anything, just run transition after you set height.

Comment: to add the transition with javascript only when the height is set, you can define the transition rule in a separate class, and add this transition class dynamically with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run transition *after* height is set. For this you extract transition rule into separate class which would be set after the height. Try something like this:

```
.accordion__item .accordion__item__content {
    height: 0;
    display:block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.accordion__item .accordion__item__content.height-set {
    transition: height 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

and in javascript:

```
content.classlist.add('height-set')
content.style.height =  content.scrollHeight + "px";
```